# SonarQube 5.3 : There's no changeset on line error message when enabling Cobertura coverage

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, cobertura, sonarqube5.3

We face the following issue when running analysis on Sonarqube 5.3 with the following plugins:

- Java 3.9
- Findbugs 3.3
- Checkstyle 2.4
- PMD 2.5
- SQALE 2.7
- SVN 1.2
- LDAP 1.5.1
- JIRA 1.2
- Cobertura 1.6.3

The batch on server side fails with the following stack trace:

```
2016.02.15 13:42:03 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVLlKjxm0XDI7xkdRnLC
org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitException: Visit failed for Component {key=com.mycompany:myapp:src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/TransferRule.java,type=FILE}  located com.mycompany:myapp:src/main/java/com/bnpparibas/app(type=DIRECTORY)->com.mycompany:myapp(type=MODULE)->com.mycompany:myapp(type=PROJECT)
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitException.rethrowOrWrap(VisitException.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:52) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:87) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:87) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:87) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.NewCoverageMeasuresStep.execute(NewCoverageMeasuresStep.java:113) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:72) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:81) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:56) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) [na:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There's no changeset on line 32
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:125) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.scm.ScmInfoImpl.getChangesetForLine(ScmInfoImpl.java:64) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.scm.DbScmInfo.getChangesetForLine(DbScmInfo.java:69) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.NewCoverageMeasuresStep$NewCoverageCounter.initialize(NewCoverageMeasuresStep.java:391) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.processLeaf(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:165) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.process(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:142) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.visitFile(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:122) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitNode(PathAwareCrawler.java:105) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:73) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
... 25 common frames omitted
```

Before running the Scanner we have build the project using Maven goal `cobertura:cobertura`

If we build the project without the coverage we don't have this issue but we lose the coverage information.

What's wrong?

For your information `sonar.scm.disabled` is left by default ie it is set to false.

Comment: After excluding two Java source files by settings sonar.coverage.exclusions accordingly, the batch analysis run successfully. What's wrong?

Comment: I think that this issue can be related with cache. Try to stop server, remove `data/es` directory, start server and run your Jenkins job.

Comment: Already performed this action. The problem still persists.

Comment: I got around this by disabling sonar analysis for the file causing the problem. To find that file I had to get admin privileges for the Sonar server to view the background analysis results for my project. See my exchange with @G. Ann from Sonar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157841/sonarqube-why-are-background-tasks-only-viewable-by-admins/36158666?noredirect=1#comment59963771_36158666). This is only a workaround until Sonar fixes their problem.

Comment: Seems like duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201372/sonarqube-5-3-illegalargumentexception-theres-no-changeset-on-line-1352#