# sonarqube: why are background tasks only viewable by admins?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

We are testing an upgrade to Sonarqube5.3 and are having some of the issues identified in other StackOverflow posts, such as the Cobertura interactions. The problem I have is that I am not an administrator for the test server, so I can't look at the background tasks to find out why they are failing. Is there a way that the background task results can be printed in the sonar analysis logs? And is there a way to get the analysis in the build not to generate an exception when the background task fails, so that it just prints an error? Can the permissions for "view background tasks" be changed from just administrators?

Answer (score 1):

The presumption is that non-admins don't care about background tasks except whether the most recent one has succeeded/failed.

Unfortunately, you're not going to be able to see server-side processing errors on the client side. The scanner compiles an analysis report and submits that to the server for processing, where it's queued and handled asynchronously.

What might work for you is requesting admin permissions, not on the SonarQube instance, but only on the project you're trying to analyze. That would give you access to the list of that project's background tasks (as well as the ability to administer the project more generally).

Comment: Do you have a ticket to at least get the server side errors not to cause client side exceptions? That looks like your left hand can't handle what it knows your right hand is doing.

Comment: I should also mention, since you otherwise never get the positive feedback, that I am liking the UI changes in 5.3 (vs 4.5). In particular I noticed that if I view a rule that I don't even have enabled on my QP I can still see if my project has violations of the rule. Really not sure how that works (unless you analyze every rule, whether enabled or not), but it saves me guessing what will happen if I enable a rule.

Comment: Uhm... if you're seeing client-side exceptions, that's happening long before the analysis report is submitted to the server. There's really no feedback from the server to the client side unless you have the Build Breaker plugin installed. Also, if you're seeing issues in the server UI, then the rules are enabled. Perhaps a different profile than you thought is being used for your project.
And thanks for the kind words. :-)

Comment: I get this in my bamboo log:
build 21-Mar-2016 07:08:50 [INFO] Executing post-job org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.QualityGateBreaker
build 21-Mar-2016 07:08:51 [INFO] Waiting for report processing to complete...

Comment: ... From my bamboo log
[INFO] Waiting for report processing to complete...
then the reactor summary, then BUILD FAILURE and:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project main: Report processing did not complete successfully: FAILED -> [Help 1]
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Report processing did not complete successfully: FAILED
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Report processing did not complete successfully: FAILED
(QualityGateBreaker.java:138)
Which doesn't look asynchronous.

Comment: "QualityGateBreaker.java:138" you have a plugin on the server side which is designed to break the client-side analysis job when the project fails the Quality Gate.

Comment: I appreciate the ongoing feedback.I don't have a gate defined, so I don't see why the breaker would stop me for any reason. Also, the analysis on the server is failing because it can't read a coverage.xml file, which doesn't seem to have the problem of a line 0 in it.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There's no changeset on line 0
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:125) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
 at org.sonar.server.computation.scm.ScmInfoImpl.getChangesetForLine(ScmInfoImpl.java:64) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]

Comment: If the gate breaker is going to stop me it shouldn't be with an exception anyway, it should say "you exceeded this measure" or something.  I'm hoping to find a solution for this that lets me keep SCM blame and Cobertura coverage analysis and therefore pass the User Acceptance Test for 5.3. Otherwise I'm going to have to request o stay on 4.5 and I like the new UI better. Just not the server side analysis.

Comment: I had my server admin grant me project admin privileges. It then showed me the adminstration tab and let me got to the background tasks page, but when I clicked to see a log I got `{"errors":[{"msg":"Insufficient privileges"}]} `. He ended up giving me server admin privileges as a workaround on the test only server for the UAT. Is this a bug?